# Use of undeclared identifier in my Objective-C code

Tags: objective-c, global-variables

I'm a newbie to Objective-C and I'm trying to a access a global variable and I can not. What have I missed?

This is the variable: `getShoppingCartRequestSuccessful`

```
-(void)setShoppingCartGetRequestWithNetworkManager//watch the bag button->4 { 
    //Sets the loading indicator on. [self setLoadingIndicator]; 
    //NetworkManager [[NetworkManager sharedManager] setDelegate:self]; 
    //GetShoppingCart [[NetworkManager sharedManager] 
    requestGetShoppingCartWithParameters:[[ServerRequestBuilder sharedManager] 
    returnParametersDictionaryForGetShoppingCartWithCustomerID:strCustomerID]]; 
    //update shopping cart-getShoppingCartRequestSuccessful [[GlobalVariables sharedManager] setObject:shoppingCartSummary 
    forKey:GLOBALVARIABLES_SHOPPINGCARTSUMMARY overwrite:YES];
}
```

This is the argument I want to pass:

```
-(void)getShoppingCartRequestSuccessful:(MNShoppingCart *)shoppingCart withOpertaion:(AFHTTPRequestOperation *)operation
{
    if (shoppingCart) {
        MNShoppingCartSummary *shoppingCartSummary = [[MNShoppingCartSummary alloc] initShoppingCartSummaryWithCustomerID:[[shoppingCart getCustomerInfoModel] getCustomerInfoID] andWithTotalAmountOfProducts:[shoppingCart getAmountOfProducts] andWithTotalPrice:[shoppingCart getTotalPrice]];
        [[GlobalVariables sharedManager] setObject:shoppingCartSummary forKey:GLOBALVARIABLES_SHOPPINGCARTSUMMARY overwrite:YES];
        NSLog(@"price val call Func #6");
        [self setShoppingCartScreenWithShoppingCartModel:shoppingCart withDeliveryAreaChange:YES];
    }
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking. You're saying that you can't access a global variable but you're not mentioning what variable, where it's defined, or where and how you're trying to access it.

Comment: Also, the code in your question is not formatted well which makes it hard to read. Please format it the way it appear in your editor: with comments and statements of separate lines.

Comment: `getShoppingCartRequestSuccessful` is a method, not a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

`getShoppingCartRequestSuccessful` is an instance method. Not a variable. Instance method is basically a "function" that can return something or even nothing (void) to the caller. In your case, is returning a void.

When you see instance method, like this

```
-(void)goDoSomething:(NSString *)name
```

To call it, if the method is in the same Viewcontroller (ie. Class), then you do it like this:

```
[self goDoSomething:@"Moran"];
```

As you can see, goDoSomething expects ONE parameter of type NSString, so you have to give it that. This will execute the method.

In your case,

```
-(void)getShoppingCartRequestSuccessful:(MNShoppingCart *)shoppingCart withOpertaion:(AFHTTPRequestOperation *)operation
```

means, you need to pass 2 parameters to it.
To use this method, you call:

```
[self getShoppingCartRequestSuccessful:yourCart withOpertaion:operation];
```

you need to have the yourCart and operation ready before passing it to this method.

ps. `withOpertaion` is wrong spelling.

Comment: thank you for the info', I've tried to call the func' this way:    [delegate getShoppingCartRequestSuccessful:[[ServerResponseParser sharedManager] parseResponseToShoppingCartModel:responseObject] withOpertaion:[RequestOperationsManager sharedManager].requestOperationGetShoppingCart]. and getting an error of Use of undeclared identifier 'delegate'..

Comment: why do you put delegate there? Is getShoppingCartRequestSuccessful a delegate function? Delegate functions should not be called manually. They often automatically called.